# Slow Computer after RAM Upgrade

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have an older Acer laptop (2009) which only had 3GB RAM. I decided to upgrade it to 8GB RAM (2x4GB, same speed like the old one).

I also formatted my hard drive and installed a fresh copy of Windows 7 x64.

During the installation, I noticed that the laptop was extremely slow (took about 3 hours to install the OS). After Windows finished installing, the computer took almost 20 minutes to boot and it was basically unusable after it booted.

Considering this is a fresh OS install, I thought the new RAM could be the only issue (both the BIOS and the OS detected the full 8GB).

I put the old 3GB RAM in (1GB + 2GB sticks) and it was fast. At this point, I thought one of the new RAM sticks must be bad.

I took out the 3GB (1GB + 2GB) and put one of the new 4GB sticks. The laptop was fast. I tried the same with the other new 4GB stick and it was still fast.

I then thought that perhaps one of the slots are bad, so I tried each slot individually with only one stick and it was still fast.

Then I tried the following combinations:

- 4GB new + 1GB old = fast
- 4GB new = fast (with either of the two sticks in either of the two slots)
- 2GB old + 1GB old = fast
- 4GB new + 2GB old = slow
- 4GB new + 4GB new = slow

I have no logical explanation for this. It seems that for up to 5GB, it's fast. If I add more than 5GB, it becomes EXTREMELY slow (5 minutes to boot).

I tested the new RAM (2x4GB) in another laptop just to make sure and it's working great.

The only processes running on the laptop are the ones that run on a fresh Windows 7 installation.

I checked task manager when the computer is slow and I noticed that the CPU usage fluctuates between 30% and 100% even when laptop is idle. There isn't one single process that is eating up the CPU, but rather a few different Windows processes and the usage keeps going up and down without me doing anything on the laptop.

Any thoughts on this are appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What model is the laptop? What's the specs on the new RAM?

Comment: I always hate to recommend this, but have you checked with Acer support? I've had issues with RAM upgrades for HP laptops before, and HP support provided me a specialized BIOS flash to get everything working. Its worth a shot.

Comment: The laptop model is Acer Aspire 5810TZ-4657. The new RAM is PC3-8500 1066MHz. I did not check with Acer support since the laptop is so old. I assumed they won't help, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: It sounds like you might need a BIOS update.  The high CPU use is intriguing. Can you run [Process Explorer](https://live.sysinternals.com/procexp.exe) from Microsoft and tell us what processes are using all the CPU? A screen shot would be good.

Comment: Thank you guys. The BIOS update did the trick! It's working great now. In case someone else with the same laptop ever runs into this issue, this is the BIOS update I used: http://drivers.softpedia.com/get/BIOS/Acer/Acer-Aspire-5810TZ-BIOS-235.shtml

Comment: @LeuName it would be worth adding your solution as an answer and telling people where to get the update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BIOS update did the trick! It's working great now. In case someone else with the same laptop ever runs into this issue, this is the BIOS update I used: http://drivers.softpedia.com/get/BIOS/Acer/Acer-Aspire-5810TZ-BIOS-235.shtml

For some reason, the old BIOS version caused the terrible slowness whenever I put over 5GB RAM in the laptop.

Thank you to those who commented!